# Changing deafult date format - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to change the default date format of my database to this: *01-Jan-2009*; but I can't understand how: I know I have to use the command `SET DATESTYLE` but I don't know which parameters should I use to achieve the result I want.

Comment: Actually most databases (I am not sure about SQLite) have no "default date format" because the date value is a numeric type. Talking about **input** format some DBMSes supports implicit/explicit conversion from the text representation of the date, but the **output** is a task of a client software (except if you explicitly convert the date value to the text using, for example `to_char` function)

Comment: Don't. Format the date in the client app, or use `to_char` to format it explicitly.

Comment: ok, I'm using pgadmin and I can think only to change sever properties to show the date in another format, but to do this I have to modify the datestyle parameters in the server config file and I don't know the parameters to use

Answer (score 0):

show postgresql.conf file

and documents https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

> The date/time styles can be selected by the user using the SET
>   datestyle command, the DateStyle parameter in the postgresql.conf
>   configuration file, or the PGDATESTYLE environment variable on the
>   server or client. The formatting function to_char is also available as
>   a more flexible way to format date/time output.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET datestyle to "ISO, DMY"
```

This would ensure that the dates have to be saved in the database with the format "dd/mm/yyyy", but the output will always be "yyyy/mm/dd", you have to format the output then if you need to.